# Routing Failure Report for "Routing Failure Report for A1.A1Process"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm getting strange suspended messages with error saying :
This service instance exists to help debug routing failures for instance "{GUID}". The context of the message associated with this instance contains all the promoted properties at the time of the routing failure.

However there is no other suspended messages  and there is no indication what was wrong into fields of this message.

How can I find out what could these messages to appear ?

Comment: What is the message in the Messages tab?

Comment: There is suspended message in there without body.However there is information about message type and Receive location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing failures never contain messages bodies, your only hope is the available context properties on the routing failure report. So analyse where they should have been going to, and figure out why they couldn't be routed to that location.